# Run multiple qunit tests in parallel with gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, qunit

I'm working on a project with several custom-made jQuery plugins and each has its own QUnit test with its own html fixture, so my `gulp-qunit` task is made like this:

```
gulp.task('qunit', () => {
    let path = './assets/test/components/**/*.html';
    return gulp.src(path)
        .pipe(qunit());
})
```

However, this way the tests are run in sequence and the whole test suite takes more than 80% of my whole build process, which I recently migrated to gulp from grunt in order to be able to parallelize some tasks.

Is there a way to run the QUnit tests in parallel, since they are not dependent on each other?

Comment: What `gulp` version do you use?

Comment: i'm using gulp v3.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a stream for each `.html` file.

That means you have to resolve your glob to an array of files, map each file into its own stream, then merge all streams into a single one:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var qunit = require('gulp-qunit');
var glob = require('glob');
var merge = require('merge-stream');

gulp.task('qunit-parallel', () => {
    var files = glob.sync('./assets/test/components/**/*.html');
    return merge(files.map(function(file) {
      return gulp.src(file).pipe(qunit());
    }));
})
```

I tried this with 100 `.html` files and it is indeed much faster:

```
[11:09:40] Finished 'qunit-sequential' after 22 s
[11:09:58] Finished 'qunit-parallel' after 2.92 s
```

Comment: That made it go from `1.47 min` to `17 s`, so it's definitely what I was looking for: I have some failures appearing randomly due to some timeouts, but I think that's outside the scope of the question, so thanks!